# applying mulitlevel json to endpoint response

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code deployed as web app on google sheets

```
function doGet(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/sskey/edit#gid=0");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("TV_Series");
  return getData(sheet); 
}

function getData(sheet){
  var jo = {};
  var dataArray = [];
  var rows = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  Logger.log("rows = "+rows);
  
  for(var i = 0, l= rows.length; i<l ; i++){
    var dataRow = rows[i];
    Logger.log("i ="+i);
    Logger.log("dataRoes = " +dataRow);
    var record = {};
    record['series_name'] = dataRow[0];
    record['season_name'] = dataRow[1];
    record["season_number"] = dataRow[2];
    record["episode_name"] = dataRow[3];
    record["episode_number"] = dataRow[4];
    record["media_url"] = dataRow[8];
    dataArray.push(record);    
  }  
  
  jo.series = dataArray;
  var result = JSON.stringify(jo);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

So the web app url returns the following JSON:

```
{"series":
[{"series_name":"Dance Academy","season_name":"season 3","season_number":"3","episode_name":"Glue","episode_number":"1","media_url":"https://someurl.net/path"},
{"series_name":"Dance Academy","season_name":"season 3","season_number":"3","episode_name":"New Rules","episode_number":"2","media_url":"https://someurl.net/path"}]}
```

i would like to separate series, seasons, and episodes to different objects in the JSON file. So i will get something like that:

```
{
 "series":{"name": "Dance Academy",
  "seasons":
   [{"name":"season 1","season_number":1,"episodes":
    [{"name":"episode 1","episode_number":1,"url":"https://someurl.net/path"},
     {"name":"episode 2","episode_number":2,"url":"https://someurl.net/path"}]},
    {"name": "season 2", "season_number":2,"episodes":
    [{"name":"episode 1","episode_number":1,"url":"https://someurl.net/path"},
     {"name":"episode 2","episode_number":2,"url":"https://someurl.net/path"}]}]}}
```

How do i do that?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

This assumes there is only one "series".  Here is an example script to build a multilevel object from the sample json.  You have to build the first object outside of any loop so that you have something to compare with inside the loops.

**Code.gs**

```
function testJson() {
  try {
    let json = {"series":
[{"series_name":"Dance Academy","season_name":"season 3","season_number":"3","episode_name":"Glue","episode_number":"1","media_url":"https://someurl.net/path"},
{"series_name":"Dance Academy","season_name":"season 3","season_number":"3","episode_name":"New Rules","episode_number":"2","media_url":"https://someurl.net/path"}]};
    let result = {};
    let series = json.series[0];
    let name = series.series_name;
    result.series = { name: name, seasons: [ { name: series.season_name, season_number: series.season_number, episodes: [] }] };
    result.series.seasons[0].episodes.push( { name: series.episode_name, episode_number: series.episode_number, media_url: series.media_url } );

    for( let i=1; i<json.series.length; i++ ) {
      series = json.series[i];
      result.series.seasons.forEach( season => {
          if( season.name === series.season_name ) {
            season.episodes.push( { name: series.episode_name, episode_number: series.episode_number, media_url: series.media_url } );
          }
          else {
            // add a new season
            let j = season.push( { name: series.season_name, season_number: series.season_number, episodes: [] } );
            season[j-1].episodes.push( { name: series.episode_name, episode_number: series.episode_number, media_url: series.media_url } );
          }
        }
      );
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
7:48:56 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:48:59 AM  Info    {"series":{"name":"Dance Academy","seasons":[{"name":"season 3","season_number":"3","episodes":[{"name":"Glue","episode_number":"1","media_url":"https://someurl.net/path"},{"name":"New Rules","episode_number":"2","media_url":"https://someurl.net/path"}]}]}}
7:48:57 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```